# Что можно доставать из Unity? 3D модели, PDF, XLS, CAD?

Tags: unity3d, проектирование, 3d, model

Существует редактор персонажей или предметов,
Сделанный на Unity, то есть запускаем игру, и создаем какого нибудь персонажа предоставленными инструментами.
Или какую-то конструкцию.

Можем ли мы Экспортировать эту модель в "какой-то" формат прямо из игры?
Будь то `.max` `.obj` `.dwg`?

То есть перенос модели из `Unity` в `3dMax`.

Более развернутая форма вопроса:

Я хочу построить редактор для каких-то типичных моделей.

Допустим я занимаюсь проектировкой заборов, или окон,
Входные данные у меня `ширина` и `высота` забора или окна,
беру я значит и рисую в AutoCad модель окна и вганяю ее в размер, ставлю два линейных размера и формирую чертежи.

Можно ли на движке Unity построить простенький редактор, каких-то типовых конструкций?

И что меня больше всего интересует реально ли вынуть оттуда `3d модели нарисованные в нем же?`
Можно ли в нем какой-то `PDF` формировать?